# broadcast receivers Issues

Tags: android

In my app I listen for bootup receiver and once I receive it, I do some stuff
The problem I see is even when my broadcast receiver is done, app stays in the running processes.
This happens every time when the phone is started and I have customer complaining why my app stays in background even when they have not started it.
What is the best way to make sure my app does not keep running in background once I am done with rec

Comment: On Android 3.1+, you will not receive the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast until after the user has used your application at least once (e.g., from the launcher). With respect to Eclipse, your users are not using Eclipse. Eclipse reports all processes, including empty ones. Empty processes will be terminated once Android needs the RAM, no sooner. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle

Comment: Thanks CommonWare..... but where did you get information about "On Android 3.1+, you will not receive the BOOT_COMPLETED".

Comment: http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do whatever needs to be done after bootup in a service and call stopSelf() once it is done.
But even when your app is listed in the running processes tab doesn't mean that its hurting anyone. The resources used by it will be made available by the managed runtime when needed either way.

Comment: You don't even need the service. The `BroadcastReceiver` will automatically shut down once `onReceive()` is done. That being said, I agree with your assessment -- the user in question is using one of those task managers written by idiots that reports empty processes the same as non-empty processes.

Comment: @androidika, ok consider this scenrrio, I have my app preloaded and user never used it, I am listening for bootup event, so as asoon as user starts phone sees my app in the running processes.  Now why would somebody allow me to do that?

Comment: the app keeps on running until the resources are needed elsewhere. Thats pretty moch how android works. This can, in a case like you described be confunsing to tghe user. A very ugly solution to this would be calling System.exit(0); at the end of onReceive(). This will terminate the whole application and gc all of its resources. Not sure if the receiver will be working after this though. You will have to try.